# How to get the canonical SEF URL of an article in PHP?

Tags: articles, joomla-api, sef

Is there any way to get from the article it's SEF URL?

```
<?php
   $id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
   $article = JTable::getInstance("content");
?>
```

searching something like this:

```
<?php echo $article->somethingLikeCanonicalSEFURL; ?>
```

Comment: @cilap I am rejecting this edit because changing one character is not a meaningful edit.   Your suggested edit falls under the category of "no improvement whatsoever" (wording in the Review Queue).  Yes, `a` should be `an` but that, of itself, is not a worthwhile edit.  (not worth the +2 rep reward) What you could have done was: condensed `any way`, changed `it's` to `its`, removed all of the unnecessary `<?php` and `?>` tags in the code blocks, reworded the English in the sentences.  When you do wish to make an edit, please make it the "final edit" by fixing EVERYTHING possible.

Comment: @Lodder please read above comment.

Comment: @NeilRobertson please read above comment.

Answer (score 1):

To get SEF URL, pass non-SEF URL through `JRoute::_()`. To get non-SEF URL, you can use `ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute()`.

```
// Load route helper class.
JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');

// Build non-SEF URL.
$nonSefLink = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->id . ':' . $article->alias, $article->catid, $article->language);

// Build SEF URL.
$sefLink = JRoute::_($nonSefLink);
```